# Linux iptables: nf_ct_snmp: dropping SNMP packet

Tags: linux, snmp, iptables, portforwarding

I want to use port forwarding feature for SNMP behind NAT like following topology:

SNMP Agent -----(Network)-----[Public_IP]Modem[Private_IP]-------SNMP supported device

I use DD-WRT Firmware on TP-Link and created two entries for SNMP service: UDP/161 and UDP/162

But when I tried to get/set some parameters from devices, it took a long time to receive the response message and almost is Timed out.

When I see the dmesg in linux shel (on TPlink), I found that there were some strange messages like bellow:

```
nf_ct_snmp: dropping packetIN= OUT=wan1 PHYSIN=eth0 SRC=10.72.200.105 DST=10.72.157.202 LEN=22330 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=26070 PROTO=UDP SPT=161 DPT=1138 LEN=22310 MARK=0x1  
bsalg:parser failed
```

I guess that this problem relates to conntrack or iptables. Anyone please tell me know the reason and how can I use SNMP service with above topology?

Thanks in advanced.